# HTML property of siblings not changing with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I believe the simplest way to explain my problem is directly running the code snippet.

I'm trying to do a file tree structure. Basically I need an UL HTML element to properly change it's display property using JS, the code works with one UL element but if there is two UL elements (siblings) it doesn't.

Please take a look at the code snippet.

```js
function init_php_file_tree() {
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return;

    var aMenus = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (var i = 0; i < aMenus.length; i++) {
        var mclass = aMenus[i].className;
        if (mclass.indexOf("pft-directory") > -1) {
            var submenu = aMenus[i].childNodes;
            for (var j = 0; j < submenu.length; j++) {
                if (submenu[j].tagName == "A") {
                    submenu[j].onclick = function() {
                        var node = this.nextSibling;
                        while (1) {
                            if (node != null) {
                                if (node.tagName == "UL") {
                                    var d = (node.style.display == "none")
                                    node.style.display = (d) ? "block" : "none";
                                    this.className = (d) ? "open" : "closed";
                                    return false;
                                }
                                node = node.nextSibling;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    submenu[j].className = (mclass.indexOf("open") > -1) ? "open" : "closed";
                }
                if (submenu[j].tagName == "UL")
                    submenu[j].style.display = (mclass.indexOf("open") > -1) ? "block" : "none";
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
jQuery(init_php_file_tree);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li class="pft-directory">
                <a class="closed" href="#"> Parent directory </a>
                <ul style="display: none;"> 
                    <li class="pft-file ext-pdf"> File Name </li>
                    <li class="pft-file ext-doc"> Another File Name </li>
                    <p> *Note that when you see this files you should also be able to see the directories in this same level</p>
                </ul>
                <!-- This second UL element never change it's display property with the current JS -->
                <ul style="display: none;"> 
                    <li class="pft-directory"> Directory Name </li>
                    <li class="pft-directory"> Another Directory Name </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a note: you shouldn't have a `p` as a child element of a `ul`, the only valid direct descendant of a `ul` is `li`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Anyway I was using it (I won't use that element again) just to clarify my question, not in my real code.

Comment: I updated the answer to fix your newest edits!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use jquery methods `toggle` and `toggleClass`

```js
function init_php_file_tree() {
  $('.pft-directory a').on('click', function() {
    var a = $(this)
    a.toggleClass('closed');
    $('ul', a.parent()).toggle();
  });
};
jQuery(init_php_file_tree);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="pft-directory">
        <a class="closed" href="#">Parent directory </a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">File Name </li>
          <li class="pft-file ext-doc">Another File Name </li>
        </ul>
     
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li class="pft-directory">Directory Name </li>
          <li class="pft-directory">Another Directory Name </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

        <!-- There's a problem with your solution (and maybe with my question, sorry!). If you have more than 2 directories in the same level they all expand and collapse, no matter wich one you click --> 
        
      <li class="pft-directory">
        <a class="closed" href="#">Parent directory </a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">File Name </li>
          <li class="pft-file ext-doc">Another File Name </li>
        </ul>

        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li class="pft-directory">Directory Name </li>
          <li class="pft-directory">Another Directory Name </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```