# Toggle on only one node with the same class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a file tree. With the code I have now I can only show and hide all the directories on the tree, it doesn't matter which node I click.

I need to be able to maintain the same class name but only show/hide the element I click on.

Check the code snippet please.

```js
function init_php_file_tree() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('closed');
    $('.pft-directory ul').toggle();
  });
};
jQuery(init_php_file_tree);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head> 

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="pft-directory">
        <a class="closed" href="#">Parent directory </a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">File Name </li>
          <li class="pft-file ext-doc">Another File Name </li>
        </ul>
      
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li class="pft-directory">Directory Name </li>
          <li class="pft-directory">Another Directory Name </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

        <!-- If you have more than 2 directories in the same level they all expand and collapse, no matter which one you click --> 
        
      <li class="pft-directory">
        <a class="closed" href="#">Parent directory </a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">File Name </li>
          <li class="pft-file ext-doc">Another File Name </li>
        </ul>

        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li class="pft-directory">Directory Name </li>
          <li class="pft-directory">Another Directory Name </li>
        </ul>
      </li> 

    </ul>
  </body> 

</html>
```

Comment: `$('.pft-directory ul')` is a global lookup.  You want a contextual lookup based on the element clicked, or whatever event you have.

Comment: Why are you bothering to add the `closed` class if you aren't going to use it?

Comment: @Anthony I use it on the style sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change your code a bit to target specific element like the one below?

```js
function init_php_file_tree() {

$('.pft-directory')  
  .on('click', function() {
     $(this).children('ul').toggle();
  })
  .children("ul").hide();
};
jQuery(init_php_file_tree);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works but I need to implement this on Wordpress and it's showing all the tree expanded (although it toggles as it should). Any idea on why?

Comment: Not sure on what you mean "all the tree expanded", i have the jsfille here https://jsfiddle.net/ns4h2v1n/8/ and it only expand whenever you click the parent node.

Comment: yes, I know that. But It seems like I need to do 1 more step in order to implement this on wordpress (I know it should be working) I think I may need to make sure to have the UL elements on display: none first. could you help me?

Comment: I've modified the code to hide all child 'ul' elements first, hope this will fix it.

Comment: Indeed it does, but now there is a new problem :( if you click on a child directory, the parent collapses (and when you click the parent again child is expended -as it should). Anyway I believe you point me into the right direction and I fall short expressing my needs.

Comment: This is my original problem and the JS code to solve almost all the incidents  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326780/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the correct elements `.pft-directory` and use the function `children` to show/hide the `ul` elements.

```
    +-- Correct selector
    |
    v
$('.pft-directory').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('closed');    
    $(this).children('ul').toggle();
            ^
            |
            +---- Get the 'ul' elements
});
```

```js
function init_php_file_tree() {
  $('.pft-directory').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('closed');    
    $(this).children('ul').toggle();
  });
};
jQuery(init_php_file_tree);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head> 

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="pft-directory">
        <a class="closed" href="#">Parent directory </a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">File Name </li>
          <li class="pft-file ext-doc">Another File Name </li>
        </ul>
      
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li class="pft-directory">Directory Name </li>
          <li class="pft-directory">Another Directory Name </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

        <!-- If you have more than 2 directories in the same level they all expand and collapse, no matter wich one you click --> 
        
      <li class="pft-directory">
        <a class="closed" href="#">Parent directory </a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li class="pft-file ext-pdf">File Name </li>
          <li class="pft-file ext-doc">Another File Name </li>
        </ul>

        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li class="pft-directory">Directory Name </li>
          <li class="pft-directory">Another Directory Name </li>
        </ul>
      </li> 

    </ul>
  </body> 

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works but I need to implement this on Wordpress and it's showing all the tree expanded (although it toggles as it should). Any idea on why?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code look like this

```
$('.pft-directory ul').toggle();  => $(this).find("ul").toggle();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works but I need to implement this on Wordpress and it's showing all the tree expanded (although it toggles as it should). Any idea on why?

Comment: What you mean "expanded" all togle is open?

Comment: Yes it is, I believe it's a Wordpress-jQuery thing. UL elements need to be hide before. @hallie has provided me with a solution but that solution creates another problem, now a parent directory collapses when his child directory expands.

Comment: This is my original problem and the JS code to solve almost all the incidents (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326780/) can you take a look?